Outline (Bookmark) from dict with unusual properties
I've extracted outlines from one pdf using source.outline, the dict that I get looks like this: {'/Title': 'U1507', '/Page': IndirectObject(30, 0, 2636377839952), '/Type': '/FitR', '/Left': 299, '/Bottom': 425, '/Right': 316, '/Top': 410, '/%is_open%': True}
I can write it to a new pdf using output.add_outline_item_dict(), but all properties aren't written to the new pdf. When I read back the outline from the new pdf I get this dict: {'/Title': 'U1507', '/Page': NullObject, '/Type': '/Fit', '/Count': 0, '/%is_open%': True}
I'm using pypdf 4.2.0.
Anybody know how to write this dict with pypdf? If it's not possible to write such a dict I can try to retain it or clone it using clone_reader_document_root(), but I must change the title of the root outline and I'm not sure if that's possible with pypdf without extracting it and writing it back.
I've managed to do this with PyMuPDF(fitz), but I'd like to be able to do it with pypdf as well.
